# 0 divided by 0 Getting NaN(Not a Number) In Android

Tags: java, sqlite, divide-by-zero

I want to do some calculation in my app where i divide two value lets say A and B. Some time A and B value are 0.0 and 0.0 respectively at that time i Get the output as `NaN`(While debugging the code) and also on `Toast`, But when i insert the value in `sqlite db` there is nothing but the blank field is inserted, why is like that can anyone explain please. NOTE: my db field is double type. thanks

Comment: If B is 0, then skip the division. Show a toast saying "Can't divide by 0".

Comment: ur insertion query might be wrong.check the query.

Comment: i can do that but y nan is not inserting in db ?

Comment: @deepak825 my query is correct everything works fine

Comment: nan is not the double value

Comment: if Nan is String then it should show error..

Comment: it seems that your insertions query may be wrong or check your data type in the database for that field .

Comment: @Jigs My query is correct

Comment: just text your query hear and let me know your data type in db

Comment: i am not asking about insertion just about the NaN @Jigs please read my question

Comment: its ok . i think @laalto is ri8 .

Comment: @Jigs that is was wat i wanted thanks for the interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally sqlite stores NaN values as NULL. It makes sense because in computational expressions, a NaN or NULL makes the whole expression NaN or NULL.

If you want to store a NaN explictly, you can store `'NaN'` as text for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to **validate** the `NaN` in android, use [`Double.isNaN(a/b)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#isNaN%28double%29). It will return true, when the argument is `NaN` and false in all valid division operations.

Comment: Yup it is helpful but not for my question, +1 for `isNaN()`